# Decoherence and quantum to classical limit: good resources?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, decoherence, foundations

I am looking for good references for decoherence theory.

I mainly worked with "*[Decoherence, einselection, and the quantum origins of the classical](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0105127)*" from Zurek, but some parts are a little bit confusing in his explanations.

I found this video https://www.perimeterinstitute.ca/videos/decoherence-entanglement-and-foundation-quantum-mechanics which looks great.

I am looking for more well explained collection of videos or really pedagogical articles/books.

What can you advise me ?

Comment: The link to the video is dead. But I think this is the video- http://pirsa.org/displayFlash.php?id=07030021

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zurek has a more public-oriented intro/overview, if you are into the popular picture pond,

- W Zurek, 2003, [Decoherence and the transition from quantum to classical -- REVISITED](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306072)

There is also a popular go-to book by Schlosshauer,

- M Schlosshauer, 2008, [Decoherence and the Quantum-to-Classical Transition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540357734)   , Springer, ISBN-13: 978-3540357735  .

To get serious, you might try technical reviews,

- K Modi, A Brodutch, H Cable, T Paterek, and V Vedral, 2012, *Rev. Mod. Phys.*   **84**, 1655, [The classical-quantum boundary for correlations: Discord and related measures](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.84.1655)
- M Schlosshauer, 2005, *Rev. Mod. Phys.* **76**, 1267, [Decoherence, the measurement problem, and interpretations of quantum mechanics](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.76.1267),

and, finally, papers like

- L E Ballentine, 2004, *Phys. Rev.*  **A70**, 032111, [Quantum-to-classical limit in a Hamiltonian system](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.70.032111).

It's a cottage industry. The essence is in the useful math tricks, not the poetic "picture" stuff.